# Two identical objects, when changing a value in one it changes in other, too

Tags: javascript

I have an object, and I copy that object into another variable and when I change either of the objects’ properties it gets reflected in the other object.

```js
(function() {
  let strA = {
    name: "John",
    age: "31",
    city: "New York"
  };
  let strB = strA;

  strA.name = "Ben";

  console.log(strA);
  console.log(strB);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is this and how do I stop it from happening?

** EDIT **

As I dug deeper into my code the assign works fine until I added an array of objects to it, as shown here

```
(function() {
  let strA = {
    name: "John",
    age: "31",
    city: "New York",
    stuff: [
        {color: "blue"},
        {color: "yellow"},
        {color: "red"}
    ]
  };
  let strB = Object.assign({}, strA);

  strB.name = "Ben";
  strB.stuff[0].color = "pink";
  
  console.log(strA);
  console.log(strB);
})();
```

This also changes the original object, I have tried this to no avail

```
(function() {
  let strA = {
    name: "John",
    age: "31",
    city: "New York",
    stuff: [
        {color: "blue"},
        {color: "yellow"},
        {color: "red"}
    ]
  };
  let strB = Object.assign({}, strA);
  strb.stuff = Object.assign({}, strA.stuff);
  
  strB.name = "Ben";
  strB.stuff[0].color = "pink";
  
  console.log(strA);
  console.log(strB);
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't copying the object. You are making a reference to it. They are the same object. You can make a copy with object.assign.

```
let strB = Object.assign({}, strA);
```

Comment: It just happens to be a deep copy in this case. `Object.assign`, in general, does _not_ create a deep copy.

Comment: This works, however, I have an array of objects in the object, which I didn't show. When I change a property in the nested object, the original gets changed as well

Comment: found the solution

Comment: Yeah your nested array is just a ref in the copy. I shouldn't have said deep copy. It just makes a new unique object with the same stuff inside.